# How can i only allow pre-configured values as props

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

So, I have a Use case where I want a form to accept only "New" OR "Update" as values in a Prop named `FormType`, any other values will result in an error msg.

I am using the script setup method, so I have defined props as follows

```
defineProps({
  FormTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  FormType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validator: (val) => {
      return ["New", "Update"].includes(val);
    },
  },
});
```

Now the issue is that other devs when using the component have to check the code to see what are the default values as they cannot see the "new" or "update" in the preview window when the roll over the mouse on that component

Here is what they see:

[image]

1. Is there any way I can tell other coders who use the component that "New" OR "Update" are the only acceptable values in prop `FormType`.
2. Is there any way I can show "New" OR "Update" are the only acceptable values in prop `FormType` in the preview window when someone rolls the mouse on the component tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a message in console.warn() when the validation fails to inform the dev of exactly what values you expect from them, thereafter you can return the validation state from an initial constant holding it. Also, add specify `@values` in your prop docBlock, this should hold your allowed values. For instance:

```js
defineProps({
  FormTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  /**
  * @values small, normal, large
  */
  FormType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validator: (v) => {
      const val = ["New", "Update"].includes(v);
      if (!val) {
         console.warn("Prop FormType can only have a value of 'New' or 'Update'");
      }
      return val
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The `console.warn()` technically solves the Point 1 , however using 
```
  /**
  * @values small, normal, large
  */ ``` 
does not show any msg in the pop-up

Comment: It works for me somehow, I'll play around and see what's going on, and I'll update my answer with any relevant info.